# How to remove duplicates where id is on different columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem removing duplicates. What makes duplicates here is I below with an example.

```
EmployeeID  IDnr1   IDnr2
123456      111111  222222
123456      222222  111111
```

I want to remove one of these lines. Does not matter who.
I have several thousand such duplicate lines.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Eventually there is no duplicate.. it is in different columns and has a different value

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause.

**Query**

```
select [EmployeeID], min([IDnr1]) [IDnr1], max([IDnr2]) [IDnr2]
from [your_table_name]
group by [EmployeeID],
case when [IDnr1] > [IDnr2] then [IDnr1] else [IDnr2] end,
case when [IDnr1] > [IDnr2] then [IDnr2] else [IDnr1] end;
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/663846/how-to-remove-duplicates-where-id-is-on-different-columns)**

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is use a cte with `row_number()`.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    EmployeeID  int,
    IDnr1  int,
    IDnr2  int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(123456, 111111, 222222),
(123456, 222222, 111111),
(123456, 111112, 222222),
(123457, 222222, 111111)
```

The cte - note the use of case to get the minimum value:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  EmployeeID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID,
            CASE WHEN IDnr1 < IDnr2 THEN IDnr1 ELSE IDnr2 END, 
            CASE WHEN IDnr1 < IDnr2 THEN IDnr2 ELSE IDnr1 END
            ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM @T
)
```

The delete statement:

```
DELETE 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZWOR71805)

**However**, deleting the duplicates is only a part of the work. You want to make sure no new duplicates can be inserted to the table. To do that, you need to add a check constraint to your table, but first, update the table.
This step will make sure you can add the check constraint:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Idnr1 = Idnr2,
    Idnr2 = Idnr1
WHERE Idnr1 >= Idnr2
```

Then, add the check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_TableNamePreventDups CHECK(Idnr1 < Idnr2)
GO
```

This will make sure no new duplicates can be inserted to your table.